# Read a text file and store numbers in different arrays in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I am currently writing my thesis, and in that context I need to develop a meta-heuristic using java. However I am facing a problem when trying to read and store the data.

My file is a text file, with around 150 lines. An example of the problem is in line 5 where three integer numbers  are stated: 30, 38 and 1. I would like to store each of these as an integer called respectively L, T and S, and this goes on for many other of the lines.

Any of you who knows how to do that? If needed I can send you the txt file.

btw: this is what I've tried so far:

Main.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;


public class MAIN {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Test.readDoc("TAP_T38L30C4F2S12_03.txt");
    }   
}
```

Test.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.HashMap; 
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

private static ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
public static Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> data = new HashMap<String,               ArrayList<Integer>>();
public static String aKey;

public static void readDoc(String File) {

try{
FileReader fr = new FileReader("TAP_T38L30C4F2S12_03.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

while(true) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    if (line == null) 
    break;
else if (line.matches("\\#\\s[a-zA-Z]")){
    String key = line.split("\\t")[1];
    line = br.readLine();
    data.put(key, computeLine(line));
    }
else if (line.matches("\\\\\\#\\s(\\|[a-zA-Z]\\|,?\\s?)+")){
     String[] keys = line.split("\\t");
     line = br.readLine();
     ArrayList<Integer> results = computeLine(line);
     for (int i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
          aKey = aKey.replace("|", "");
        //  data.put(aKey, results.get(i));
          data.put(aKey, results);
     }
    }
    System.out.println(data);

    }
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();      }    
}


private static ArrayList<Integer> computeLine (String line){
    String[] splitted = line.split("\\t");
    for (String s : splitted) {
    integerList.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
    }

    return integerList;
}

}
```

And example of the data is seen here:

```
     \# TAP instance 
     \# Note that the sequence of the data is important!
     \#
     \# |L|, |T|, |S|
     30 38  1
     \#
     \# v
     8213   9319    10187   12144   8206    ...
     \#
     \# w
     7027   9652    9956    13973   6661    14751   ...
     \#
     \# b
     1  1   1   1   1   ...
     \#
     \# c
     1399   1563    1303    1303    2019    ...
     \#
     \# continues
```

Comment: 1. Java **is not** javascript. 2. Do a google search "read file java". 3. Do another google search "split line java". 4. You solved your problem with a little research.

Comment: `If needed I can send you the txt file.`.No need, just show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hey Guys, thx for the comments. To be honest I've tried for the last 4 hours and it doesn't seem that I can find the solution. (BackSlash sorry for the tag)

Comment: Much better with code! But if you had rephrased the question to match the problem you have, you'd have got results: I believe you have problems "splitting a String"...

Comment: Hey ppeterka, thx. I guess I did not know what the correct title for the problem was. I'll try to google a bit more with your suggestion and see I get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is working with the sample data you gave.

**In short** :

1. Create a field to store your data, I chose a `TreeMap` so you can map a letter to a certain number of Integers but you can use another [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html).
2. Read the file line by line using [`BufferedReader#readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)
3. Then process each bunch of lines depending on your data. Here I use [`regular expressions`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) to match a given line and then to remove everything that is not data. See [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), [`String#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)

But **before all** start by reading some good beginners books about java and Object Oriented Design.

```
public class ReadAndParse {

    public Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> data = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();

     public ReadAndParse() {
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while(true) {
                String line = br.readLine();
                if (line == null)    break;

                else if (line.matches("\\\\#\\s[a-zA-Z]")){
                    String key = line.split("\\s")[1];
                    line = br.readLine();

                    ArrayList<Integer> value=  computeLine(line);

                    System.out.println("putting key : " + key + " value : " + value);
                    data.put(key, value);
                }
                else if (line.matches("\\\\\\#\\s(\\|[a-zA-Z]\\|,?\\s?)+")){
                    String[] keys = line.split("\\s");
                    line = br.readLine();

                    ArrayList<Integer> results = computeLine(line);

                    for (int i=1; i<keys.length; i++){
                        keys[i] = keys[i].replace("|", "");
                        keys[i] = keys[i].replace(",", "");

                        System.out.println("putting key : " + keys[i] + " value : " + results.get(i-1));

                        ArrayList<Integer> value=  new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        value.add(results.get(i-1));
                        data.put(keys[i],value);
                    }
                }
            }

        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // print the data
        for (Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : data.entrySet()){
            System.out.println("variable : " + entry.getKey()+" value : "+ entry.getValue() );
        }
}

    // the compute line function
    private ArrayList<Integer> computeLine(String line){
        ArrayList<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] splitted = line.split("\\s+");
        for (String s : splitted) {
            System.out.println("Compute Line : "+s);
            integerList.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        }
        return integerList;
    }

    // and the main function to call it all
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ReadAndParse();
}
}
```

Some sample output of what I got after parsing your file :

```
 variable : L value : [30]
 variable : S value : [1]
 variable : T value : [38]
 variable : b value : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 variable : c value : [1399, 1563, 1303, 1303, 2019]
 variable : v value : [8213, 9319, 10187, 12144, 8206]
 variable : w value : [7027, 9652, 9956, 13973, 6661, 14751]
```

Comment: Hi Marc, thx for the swift reply. However I have some troubles of getting it to work. I have just added an example of the data in the problem description. Could you perhaps give an example with that? Thx in advance. N

Comment: You would need to modify the computeLine function. Let me see if I can do something out of your data

Comment: @MetaNa Tried a little something to give you a headstart. I haven't tested it so use with caution. But it should give you an idea of what to do. If not do not hesitate to tell me.

Comment: Hi Marc, wow you are super fast! I have tried to implement what you suggested. But somehow it does not seem to work. I have inserted the "new code" above. Any suggestions, am I doing anything particularly wrong? Cheers, N

Comment: I can't tell you if you don't tell me what is going wrong. As I said I haven't tested the code, I'll run it and see...

Comment: Hi Marc, it is perfect. I have used your code and modified it a bit for the rest of the text file. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got something.

EDIT:

I've changed my approach

You'll need to import;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
```

Then

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader

int[] arr = new int[3];
int L;
int T;
int S;
for (int i = 0 ;i<5; i++){ //brings you to fifth line

 line = reader.readLine();
}
L = line.split(" ")[0]trim();
T = line.split(" ")[1]trim();
S = line.split(" ")[2]trim();

arr[0] = (L);
arr[1] = (T);    
arr[2] = (S);
```

Comment: Are you inventing code? What is `int Array arr = new Array [3];`?

Comment: Hi Robert, thx for the reply.
I've added an example of the code above. Could you perhaps give an example with that? Thx in advance. N